# Duplicate questions, both without an answer cannot be flagged

Tags: discussion

I am flagging a question that is a duplicate of another. I get an error. "This question does not have an upvoted or accepted answer".

Duplicate: [How do I filter out regions that are full?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/108207/how-do-i-filter-out-regions-that-are-full)
of original: [Joining a game with an empty slot](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/108028/joining-a-game-with-an-empty-slot)

Discussion: Is it ok to post duplicate questions as long as the duplicates do not have answers with upvotes. Apparently. This is a new game, so duplicates without answers will occur quickly.

Comment: Fixed for now. This isn't specific to Arqade, so I'd repost on Meta.SO

Comment: @RavenDreamer If it's reposted on MSO, it'll just be duped to a dozen other discussions on the subject. I thought we'd had one here as well, but an overaggressive mod may have migrated it to MSO...

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz I thought this was new. If it wasn't, then you're probably right.

Comment: @RavenDreamer It's [about a month and a half old.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165928/we-should-be-able-to-close-questions-as-duplicates-of-any-question)

Comment: @RavenDreamer If it's duped, hopefully there's an article with at least one answer ;)

Comment: the issue was that neither question had an answer. I just see the problem of many questions being asked about the same thing. Then no one having a clue about the answer and no way to mark any of them as duplicate. The first question being the original that should get the answer. Otherwise if a later question is answered, the original could be marked as duplicate. time for a coffee.

Comment: This question suffered from the same problem: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/106132/how-can-i-gift-a-game-via-origin which resulted in an answer and later being closed.